# Odoo Install -AttributeError: 'ir.http' object has no attribute 'webclient_rendering_context'

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, pycharm, odoo

I got this error when I try to run odoo in pycharm terminal. After configuring odoo and python in pycharm. When I get in postgres console, the database is created. Here is the full error reference.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/odoo16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1988, in __call__
    response = request._serve_db()
  File "/home/paul/odoo16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/home/paul/odoo16/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 134, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/home/paul/odoo16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1611, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/home/paul/odoo16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1724, in dispatch
    return self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/home/paul/odoo16/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/home/paul/odoo16/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 699, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/home/paul/odoo16/odoo/addons/web/controllers/home.py", line 57, in web_client
    context = request.env['ir.http'].webclient_rendering_context()
AttributeError: 'ir.http' object has no attribute 'webclient_rendering_context'
```

I want some help to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for this error one of the following:

1. uncompilable version of python with your Odoo version
2. uncompilable version of Postgres with your Odoo version
3. uncompilable versions of your python depends lib ( requirements ) with your Odoo version